# Возможен ли обмен 1c 1c bitrix через связку nginx + php-fpm?

Tags: nginx, 1с, php-fpm, битрикс

у нас есть инет-магазин, на битриксе и настроен новый обмен с 1ской через wsap22 модуль для apache. Сейчас появилась потребность в переводе сайта на связку nginx+php-fpm, все переделано, кроме собственно этого обмена. Вопросы на засыпку:

1. Есть ли аналог wsap22 для nginx для обмена 1с?
2. Если нет, то можно ли каким-то другим способом организовать обмен? Будет ли это быстрее-медленнее, чем сейчас?

Comment: Зачем вам wsap22 модуль для обмена? С каких пор он для обмена? Какого вида обмен происходит поподробнее?

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли аналог wsap22 для nginx для обмена 1с?

Нету. И подозреваю что не будет.

> Если нет, то можно ли каким-то другим способом организовать обмен?
>   Будет ли это быстрее-медленнее, чем сейчас?

Я подозреваю что 1С у вас в интернете и тонкие клиенты подсоединяются к ней через **ISS**. Сайт сбрасывает заказы в 1С через **ISS**.
Поэтому настраиваем `1c<->apache-backend(wsap22)<->nginx` для снижения расходов по памяти и процессору. Работает быстрее чем просто **ISS**.

Comment: Может IIS, а не ISS